# How do I email a PDF generated using PDFKit and on Heroku in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, actionmailer, pdfkit

I am using PDFKit on Heroku (and also locally for dev) and am having difficulty emailing the generating PDF from my cron task.

This is the code in my cron job:

```
     kit = PDFKit.new(html_file) 
     file = kit.to_pdf 

     OutboundMailer.deliver_pdf_email(file) 
     #kit.render_file("pdf_from_cron.pdf")
```

This is the code in my Mailer:

```
 def pdf_email(pdf)
  subject     "This is your batch of letters"
  recipients  "helloworld@gmail.com"
  from        "Batch Email <hello@batch.com>"
  sent_on     Date.today
  body        "This is the body of pdf"

  attachment "application/pdf" do |a|
    a.filename = "batch-letters.pdf"
    a.body = pdf
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I setup PDFKit on Heroku once and followed: http://blog.mattgornick.com/using-pdfkit-on-heroku. You may need to include the binary.

Comment: hi, yes, I was reading that blog and it references as CustomMailer....I think I did it the same as that blog but still not working...help?

Comment: @Kevin...no error in the log...I am pretty sure that I can send emails from my development box...nothing appears to being sent...

Comment: To generate the pdf on heroku: http://jguimont.com/post/2627758108/pdfkit-and-its-middleware-on-heroku and to email it afterward http://jguimont.com/post/5582583230/how-to-render-a-full-page-template-in-a-rake-task-with